# Get Attributes python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class A(object):
      a = 1
      b = 0
      c = None
      d = None
a_obj=A()
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
attrs_present = filter(lambda x: getattr(a_obj, x), a_list)
```

I want both a and b attributes, here 0 is a valid value. I don't want to use comparison==0

is there a way to get those?
Any help will be appriciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude `c`, `d` (`None`s), use `is None` or `is not None`:

```
attrs_present = filter(lambda x: getattr(a_obj, x, None) is not None, a_list)
# NOTE: Added the third argument `None`
#       to prevent `AttributeError` in case of missing attribute 
#       (for example, a_list = ['a', 'e'])
```

If you want to include `c`, `d`, use [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
attrs_present = filter(lambda x: hasattr(a_obj, x), a_list)
```

Comment: You can thank them even more by marking it as the answer. ;)